# Yodlee: endNumber and higherFetchLimit

Tags: yodlee

What is the highest acceptable number for higherFetchLimit and endNumber with the executeUserSearchRequest API?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter any number say up to 6 or even 7 digit number for HigherFetchLimit, while it is recommend to set max around 10000.

endNumber- depends upon your startNumber, as it will give you those many records out of the superset of records which were found for your query and kept in cache. Its like you are doing a pagination.

It is recommended to keep it somewhere 100-200 records(depending upon your start number).